# SVG Glyphs with Huge Dimensions

Tags: svg, fonts, glyph

This question is about the design of SVG-fonts.
I am using some [third-party SVG music fonts](https://github.com/OpenLilyPondFonts/haydn.git) for an application. The single glyphs of these fonts, are by default very huge in size. I was wondering what the reason for this could be. I can think of, this allows to do more fine-tuning work while designing the fonts, and since they are of course scalable, they should be down-scaled as needed when I want to actually use them. Is this true, or are there some other points to consider?
Also when I use the path's data of single fonts (e.g. in a svg file) and open the svg file in Inkscape the symbols are upside-down, so I have to apply scale(1 -1) to all symbols. Is there a reason why these fonts are designed this way?

Comment: Most likely the author just forgot to optimize the result. The only significant concern about what scale is used is final file size.

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky OP asked about dimensions, not file size.

Answer (score 1):

It will generally relate to the tool(s) they are using.  Font editors commonly have a default em size of around 1000 units. The reason for that is likely because font files generally use integers, rather than floating point, for their glyph coordinates.  And 1000 gives you a decent three digits of precision.

For instance [have a look at a description of the OTF/TTF `glyf` table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf)